# Windows 10 just won't work. All because of.. TVALZ.sys?

Tags: boot, windows-10

So I just refreshed my windows 10 Pc. (Keeps all my files) but now at the boot screen I'm stuck with this:

[image: something is wrong...]

System restore didn't have anything, system image didn't have anything, and startup repair was just useless. It just couldn't
Identify the problem.

This is a really serious issue as I cannot even get into my PC. Can someone help with these questions:

- What is TVALZ.sys?
- How do I fix this issue so I can get back into my PC?

Comment: its a Toshiba ACPI interface driver. you need it for power management options like CPU throttling, Hibernation/resumption, etc.

Comment: How do I fix this issue though

Comment: Is it something in the bios?

Comment: no, its a driver that allow the OS to communicate with and use the BIOS power management system, but it is OS software. the actual error is unclear in your image. could you please type it out? I don't win10, but the info will be helpful to others. you may also want to search for solutions by indicating that it is a toshiba machine. their support may be exactly what you need. good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try searching on the net for a replacement file and try that. (I will backup the original file)

Comment: I'm not really able to read your error message, but if its an 0x0000000d, that error is usually associated with the inability to connect to a network printer.

Comment: So then how am I meant to fix this then? I've tried everything and nothing has worked

Comment: Also the error code you said was correct